# Coldfusion HMAC-SHA1 encryption

Tags: encryption, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, hmacsha1

There is an example HMAC-SHA1 here that works in javascript

http://jssha.sourceforge.net/

### Text to encrypt

vibaHBXwUXFqVSg-+kTrqYJZEJkbVeqLc=bo.LlXGET12505351831husu9039http://api.tineye.com/rest/search/image_url=http%3a%2f%2ftineye.com%2fimages%2ftineye_logo_big.png&limit=30&offset=10

### Key

vibaHBXwUXFqVSg-+kTrqYJZEJkbVeqLc=bo.LlX

### Output

9e734661c9e8b6dc9b6b4b3def9769c00e8843b8

### Issue

I can't however duplicate the output in Coldfusion. I'm using a function from a previous Stackoverflow.com question

```
<cffunction name="hmacEncrypt" returntype="binary" access="public" output="false">
   <cfargument name="signKey" type="string" required="true" />
   <cfargument name="signMessage" type="string" required="true" />


   <cfset var jMsg = JavaCast("string",arguments.signMessage).getBytes("iso-8859-1") />
   <cfset var jKey = JavaCast("string",arguments.signKey).getBytes("iso-8859-1") />

   <cfset var key = createObject("java","javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec") />
   <cfset var mac = createObject("java","javax.crypto.Mac") />

   <cfset key = key.init(jKey,"HmacSHA1") />

   <cfset mac = mac.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm()) />
   <cfset mac.init(key) />
   <cfset mac.update(jMsg) />

   <cfreturn mac.doFinal() />
</cffunction>

<cfset result = hmacEncrypt("vibaHBXwUXFqVSg-+kTrqYJZEJkbVeqLc=bo.LlX", "vibaHBXwUXFqVSg-+kTrqYJZEJkbVeqLc=bo.LlXGET12505351831husu9039http://api.tineye.com/rest/search/image_url=http%3a%2f%2ftineye.com%2fimages%2ftineye_logo_big.png&limit=30&offset=10")>

<cfset x1 = toString(tobase64(result))>
```

### This returns

nnNGYcnottyba0s975dpwA6IQ7g=

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> <cfset x1 = toString(tobase64(result))>
> ```

The other function is returning hex, not base64. Other than that it seems to work fine for me:

```
 <cfset x1 = binaryEncode(result, "hex")>
```

Answer (score 3):

The clue is in your expected output string: it contains only digits and lowercase letters. If you look closer, all the letters are in the range a-f. Therefore it is extremely likely that it is a hexadecimal string.

The last line of your example code encodes the result as base64, not hexadecimal. You can encode the result as hexadecimal by changing the last line to this:

```
<cfset x1 = binaryEncode(result,"hex")>
```

I ran the modified code and got

```
9E734661C9E8B6DC9B6B4B3DEF9769C00E8843B8
```

which is the uppercase version of your expected string.

Comment: @Brettski - Actually, I believe Boomerang's response beat me by a few seconds. So if you want to accept his answer, I would not be offended :)