# Trying to use ColdFusion to create HMAC-SHA1 hash for API authentication

Tags: coldfusion, hmacsha1

I am at my wit's end on this one, I just can't find the right combination of code to make this work.  I'm trying to create an authentication digest for an API query.  I've tried many CFML functions (for example:  [Coldfusion HMAC-SHA1 encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186773/coldfusion-hmac-sha1-encryption) and [HMAC SHA1 ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959972/hmac-sha1-coldfusion)), but I'm not coming up with the same results that are cited in the API documentation.  Here's that example (basically elements of the request header with line breaks as delimiters.):

```
application/xml\nTue, 30 Jun 2009 12:10:24 GMT\napi.summon.serialssolutions.com\n/2.0.0/search\ns.ff=ContentType,or,1,15&s.q=forest\n
```

and here's the key:

```
ed2ee2e0-65c1-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66
```

which according to the documentation should result in:

```
3a4+j0Wrrx6LF8X4iwOLDetVOu4=
```

when the HMAC hash is converted to Base64. Any ideas would be most appreciated!

Comment: Is the API public? if so, what is it?  Does it come with any example code in Java or PHP?  I'd start with those usually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your input string, not the functions.  The [first one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9186773/coldfusion-hmac-sha1-encryption) works fine. Though I would change the charset to `UTF-8`, or make it an argument. Otherwise, the results are dependent on the jvm default, which may not always be correct, and can change which would break the code.

Verify you are constructing the sample string correctly. Are you using `chr(10)` for new lines? Note: It must also *end with* a new line.

**Code:**

```
<cfscript>
    headers = [ "application/xml"
                    , "Tue, 30 Jun 2009 12:10:24 GMT"
                    , "api.summon.serialssolutions.com"
                    , "/2.0.0/search"
                    , "s.ff=ContentType,or,1,15&s.q=forest"
                ];
    theText = arrayToList(headers, chr(10)) & chr(10);
    theKey = "ed2ee2e0-65c1-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66";
    theHash = binaryEncode( hmacEncrypt(theKey, theText), "base64");
    writeDump(theHash);
</cfscript>
```

**Result:**

```
3a4+j0Wrrx6LF8X4iwOLDetVOu4=
```